# Extract and tokenize second column of csv/txt input - Java

Tags: java, parsing, split, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I have an input data text/csv file of the form:

```
int x,int y <br>
int z,int y <br> 
int c,int y <br>
int y,int z <br>
```

or

```
1,6
2,7
4,6
9,6
3,9
4,9
6,1
4,1
```

I'm looking to read in the and tokenize the whole input file but only extract the second column's value so that I can later create a key - value pair where the keys will be the values in the second column. I tried to use StringTokenizer but it treats each row as it's own unique record and I'm not sure how to specifically only extract the second column for further aggregation to be performed.

Comment: Have a look at apache commons csv api https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: From the _javadoc_ for class `java.util.StringTokenizer`: _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead._

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the split() method but I'm not sure how to only extract and parse the integers in the second column while using split() and put only those into an array of strings.

Comment: Post the code you tried, so people can help you with it.